# Crash on segue to new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am having trouble adding a new view controller to my project. In the story board, i added a new view controller. Then i added the new view controller files. I added a segue from my detailed disclosure table view to this new view controller however when i run it and try to click the detailed button, it crashes and gives me this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailsViewController setCompletionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa235050'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks so much!

EDIT:

UIDetailsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIDetailsViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

UIDetailsViewController.m

```
#import "UIDetailsViewController.h"

@interface UIDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation UIDetailsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: u were set the class name to the view controller

Comment: Have you created sub class of `UIViewController` and give its name in the storyboard? Better if you [check some tutorial first](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: I just did a new file and created a new UIViewController and in the story board I selected it in the identity inspector

Comment: @Omarj I added what I have!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have `unrecognized selector` crash in your apps. It means your methods are not defined in your class or not available. Remember, private methods are not accessible via class objects.

**Edit:**

Rp: to your answer,using prepareForSegue it will be something like that so event if you don't have it this will not make any problem for you ?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EventDeatailSeg"]) {

        EventDetailViewController *editVc = segue.destinationViewController;
        editVc.myEvent = currentEvent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I didn't have the prepareForSegue for the segue to the new view controller. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: prepareForSegue ??? we use this method when u need to pass variable or object to the viewController you try to "push" ?? sound weird